# Do you need a pressure cooker to can home-made salsa?

Tags: storage-method, canning, salsa

I grew my own tomatoes this year and had success with making my own salsa.  Do you need a pressure cooker to can home-made salsa?

Comment: Note: if you do find that your salsa should be pressure-canned, be sure to check if your pressure cooker can be used for canning or not. A pressure *cooker* can't always be used for canning; you may actually need a pressure *canner*.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot preserve just any salsa recipe (unless you're just freezing it).

Tomatoes are on the border between acidic and non-acidic foods. What this means is that they can be water-bath canned if they are sufficiently high in acid; but, if they are low in acid, they need to be pressure canned.

If you want to be sure to avoid trouble, follow a tested recipe. Salsa recipes will have a careful balance of low and high acid ingredients. *Do not* alter the proportion of acids (tomatoes and vinegar or lime/lemon juice) and low-acids (other vegetables, peppers, etc).

The recipe you choose should specify if it requires pressure canning or water-bath canning. One of those two methods must be used, though... you can't just put it in jars and save it.

For tested recipes, see the [Ball Blue Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0972753702), [the Ball website](http://www.freshpreserving.com/recipes.aspx), or the [National Center for Home Food Preservation](http://www.uga.edu/nchfp/how/can_salsa.html).

Comment: Presumably if you want to test your own recipe to be completely sure, you could just measure the pH? Strips with a 0.5 resolution might be good enough, long as you err on the side of caution, though pH meters aren't really *that* expensive. (I don't have any experience, but from reading, it sounds like there's a clear pH cutoff between low- and high-acid for this purpose.)

Comment: I like the cut of your jib.

Answer (score 2):

Most salsas are pretty acidic. If that is the case with this one you should be able to safely can it without a pressure canner.

Comment: see JustRightMenus' answer.  It's not quite that simple according to the above links.  Botulism is no fun.